# Cloudflare worker redirections

Tags: cloudflare, worker

Lets say that I have a website asdf.com, and I would like to write a worker that will do a lot of redirections (more than 30). For example [www.asdf.com/app](http://www.asdf.com/app) -> app-asdf.com, [www.asdf.com/dashboard](http://www.asdf.com/dashboard) -> dashboard-asdf.com.
I tried with following, but it doesn't work:

```html
async function handleEvent(event) {
  const url = new URL(event.request.url)

  // Redirects
  const redirects = {
    'bitgravity': 'tata-communications',
    'highwinds': 'stackpath',
    'maxcdn': 'stackpath',
    'netdna': 'stackpath',
    'level3': 'centurylink',
    '/blog/feed/': '/blog/feed.xml',
    '/blogdef/': '/social/blog/',
    '/geodef/': '/social/geo/',
    '/guidedef/': '/social/guides/',
    '/blog/akamai-down/': '/blog/'
  }

  let target = null
  
  for (const source in redirects) {
    if (url.pathname.includes(source)) {
      if(target == null){
        target = new URL(url.href)
      }
      target = new URL(target.href.replace(source, redirects[source]))
    }
  }

  if (target != null){
    return Response.redirect(target, 301)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At the end of your function:

```
  if (target != null){
    return Response.redirect(target, 301)
  }
}
```

If `target` is `null` -- meaning no redirects matched -- then you are not returning any value. This will produce an exception (error 1101). When running in preview, the JS console will show the error: "Uncaught (in response) TypeError: Failed to execute function: parameter 1 is not of type 'Response'."

You probably want to change the code to:

```
  if (target != null){
    return Response.redirect(target, 301)
  }

  return fetch(event.request)
}
```

Of course, your worker also needs this at the top (but I assume you just left it out for brevity):

```
addEventListener("fetch", event => {
  return event.respondWith(handleEvent(event))
})
```